# Latest Available Holdings by Quarter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursive-query, gaps-and-islands

I'm hoping for a fix to this that doesn't use a cursor (unless necessary).

We receive holdings submissions from our Investments quarterly. They are loaded by Reference Date, Investment, Holding and currency type making each row distinct. This data is put in a database in MSFT SQL Server. Sometimes an Investment does not submit their holdings for that quarter. In that case, we would like to pull in the latest available quarter's holdings (This could be 3 or 4 quarters ago) so there is no gap when performing trending analysis over multiple reference dates.

In addition to the gaps, we need to bring forward the data from the last submission to the MAX([Reference Date]) for the entire table.  For the below, this date is 6/30/2021.

We have a date dimension table.  For submissions brought forward, the [Data Availability] column should show 'Include Latest from Previous Submissions'.

**Issue is shown in first DDL (fix is shown in 2nd DDL example):**

Issues:

- Investment 1 is missing on 6/30/2020 through 3/31/2021
- Investment 2 is missing from 3/31/2021 to 6/30/2021 (the max date)
- Investment 1, TransUnion would not be brought forward past 12/31/2019 since there was another submission on 3/31/2020 without TransUnion

Fix:

- We need a new row based on the investments most recent holdings for both Local and USD Currency Types for the missing quarter-ends.

Sample data before fix:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestInvestments
    ( [Reference Date] DATE, [Investment] [nvarchar](1000) NOT NULL, [holding] [nvarchar](1000) NOT NULL, [Currency Type] [varchar](100) NULL, [Data Availability] varchar(22), [Current Value] [float] NULL, [Current Cost] [float] NULL, [Realized] [Float] NULL)
;
    
INSERT INTO TestInvestments
    ( [Reference Date], [Investment], [holding], [Currency Type], [Data Availability], [Current Value], [Current Cost], [Realized])
VALUES

    ('2019-12-31', 'Investment 1', 'Quality Care', 'LOCAL', 'Current Qtr Submission', 0, 0, 15757000),
    ('2019-12-31', 'Investment 1', 'Quality Care', 'USD', 'Current Qtr Submission', 0, 0, 15757000),
    ('2019-12-31', 'Investment 1', 'TransUnion', 'LOCAL', 'Current Qtr Submission', 0, 0, 631410000),
    ('2019-12-31', 'Investment 1', 'TransUnion', 'USD', 'Current Qtr Submission', 0, 0, 631410000),
    ('2020-03-31', 'Investment 1', 'Quality Care', 'LOCAL', 'Current Qtr Submission', 0, 0, 15757000),
    ('2020-03-31', 'Investment 1', 'Quality Care', 'USD', 'Current Qtr Submission', 0, 0, 15757000),
    ('2020-12-31', 'Investment 2', 'West Corp.', 'LOCAL', 'Current Qtr Submission', 63872528, 54756087, 0),
    ('2020-12-31', 'Investment 2', 'West Corp.', 'USD', 'Current Qtr Submission', 63872528, 54756087, 0),
    --End of Addition
    ('2021-06-30', 'Investment 3', 'Tinkers', 'USD', 'Current Qtr Submission', 12536, 26541, 0)
;
```

Expected Results after fix would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestInvestmentsFixed
    ( [Reference Date] DATE, [Investment] [nvarchar](1000) NOT NULL, [holding] [nvarchar](1000) NOT NULL, [Currency Type] [varchar](100) NULL, [Data Availability] varchar(100), [Current Value] [float] NULL, [Current Cost] [float] NULL, [Realized] [Float] NULL)
;
    
INSERT INTO TestInvestmentsFixed
    ( [Reference Date], [Investment], [holding], [Currency Type], [Data Availability], [Current Value], [Current Cost], [Realized])
VALUES

    ('2019-12-31', 'Investment 1', 'Quality Care', 'LOCAL', 'Current Qtr Submission', 0, 0, 15757000),
    ('2019-12-31', 'Investment 1', 'Quality Care', 'USD', 'Current Qtr Submission', 0, 0, 15757000),
    ('2019-12-31', 'Investment 1', 'TransUnion', 'LOCAL', 'Current Qtr Submission', 0, 0, 631410000),
    ('2019-12-31', 'Investment 1', 'TransUnion', 'USD', 'Current Qtr Submission', 0, 0, 631410000),
    ('2020-03-31', 'Investment 1', 'Quality Care', 'LOCAL', 'Current Qtr Submission', 0, 0, 15757000),
    ('2020-03-31', 'Investment 1', 'Quality Care', 'USD', 'Current Qtr Submission', 0, 0, 15757000),
    --Data added here.  TransUnion not brought forward from 12/31/19
    ('2020-06-30', 'Investment 1', 'Quality Care', 'LOCAL', 'Include Latest from Previous Submissions', 0, 0, 15757000),
    ('2020-06-30', 'Investment 1', 'Quality Care', 'USD', 'Include Latest from Previous Submissions', 0, 0, 15757000),
    ('2020-09-30', 'Investment 1', 'Quality Care', 'LOCAL', 'Include Latest from Previous Submissions', 0, 0, 15757000),
    ('2020-09-30', 'Investment 1', 'Quality Care', 'USD', 'Include Latest from Previous Submissions', 0, 0, 15757000),    
    ('2020-12-31', 'Investment 1', 'Quality Care', 'LOCAL', 'Include Latest from Previous Submissions', 0, 0, 15757000),
    ('2020-12-31', 'Investment 1', 'Quality Care', 'USD', 'Include Latest from Previous Submissions', 0, 0, 15757000),        
    ('2021-03-31', 'Investment 1', 'Quality Care', 'LOCAL', 'Include Latest from Previous Submissions', 0, 0, 15757000),
    ('2021-03-31', 'Investment 1', 'Quality Care', 'USD', 'Include Latest from Previous Submissions', 0, 0, 15757000),
    ('2021-06-30', 'Investment 1', 'Quality Care', 'LOCAL', 'Include Latest from Previous Submissions', 0, 0, 15757000),
    ('2021-06-30', 'Investment 1', 'Quality Care', 'USD', 'Include Latest from Previous Submissions', 0, 0, 15757000),
    --End of Addition
    ('2020-12-31', 'Investment 2', 'West Corp.', 'LOCAL', 'Current Qtr Submission', 63872528, 54756087, 0),
    ('2020-12-31', 'Investment 2', 'West Corp.', 'USD', 'Current Qtr Submission', 63872528, 54756087, 0),
    --This data is added
    ('2021-03-31', 'Investment 2', 'West Corp.', 'LOCAL', 'Include Latest from Previous Submissions', 63872528, 54756087, 0), 
    ('2021-03-31', 'Investment 2', 'West Corp.', 'USD', 'Include Latest from Previous Submissions', 63872528, 54756087, 0),
    ('2021-06-30', 'Investment 2', 'West Corp.', 'LOCAL', 'Include Latest from Previous Submissions', 63872528, 54756087, 0),     
    ('2021-06-30', 'Investment 2', 'West Corp.', 'USD', 'Include Latest from Previous Submissions', 63872528, 54756087, 0),
    --End of Addition
    ('2021-06-30', 'Investment 3', 'Tinkers', 'USD', 'Current Qtr Submission', 12536, 26541, 0)
;
```

**Current solution (not working/and is a cursor)**: I think this is too much to not be in a fiddle, but I recreated this from the solution I am currently using.  This brings forward holdings it shouldn't due to bringing forward holdings like TransUnion.  There appears to be some other issues with this recreated script that I'll go through:

```
/*                       *******************     USD Only in this section - below USD is the Local       *******************************   */

IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB.dbo.#TestInvestments_USD_Only') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TestInvestments_USD_Only
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB.dbo.#nums') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #nums
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB.dbo.#TestInvestments_LatestAvailable_USD') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TestInvestments_LatestAvailable_USD

/*create temp table for USD Holdings only - Local Currency is unioned later*/
Select * into #TestInvestments_USD_Only from TestInvestments where [Currency Type] = 'USD' 

/* Table to contain the missing holdings*/
CREATE TABLE #TestInvestments_LatestAvailable_USD(
   [Reference Date] date  NOT NULL
  ,Investment nvarchar (200) NOT NULL
  ,[Holding Key] int NOT NULL
  ,Holding nvarchar (200) NOT NULL
  ,[Currency Type] [varchar](100) NULL
  ,[Data Availability] varchar(100) NULL
  ,[Current Value] [float] NULL
  ,[Current Cost] [float] NULL
  ,[Realized] [float] NULL
  ,primary key(Investment, [Holding Key], [Reference Date])
);

--cartesian join to create a table of row numbers (65,536 rows)
create table #nums(n integer not null primary key);
with
  p1 as (select 0 as n union all select 0), -- 2
  p2 as (select 0 as n from p1 cross join p1 as b), -- 4
  p3 as (select 0 as n from p2 cross join p2 as b), -- 16
  p4 as (select 0 as n from p3 cross join p3 as b), -- 256
  p5 as (select 0 as n from p4 cross join p4 as b) -- 65536
insert into #nums(n) select row_number() over(order by (select 0)) from p5;

--Create Variables for all of the USD columns to store the missing rows
declare
@prev_Investment nvarchar(200) ,@Investment nvarchar(200),
@prev_HoldingKey int, @HoldingKey int,
@prev_ReferenceDate date ,@ReferenceDate date,
@prev_Holding nvarchar(200) ,@Holding nvarchar(200),
@prev_CurrencyType varchar(100) ,@CurrencyType varchar(100),
@prev_DataAvailability varchar(100),@DataAvailability varchar(100),
@prev_CurrentValue float ,@CurrentValue float,
@prev_CurrentCost float ,@CurrentCost float,
@prev_Realized float ,@Realized float,
@qdiff integer;

--Begin loop for USD to look for missing rows based on Investment, holdingkey and reference date, and add missing data to a variables

declare
  c cursor forward_only static read_only for
    select Investment, [Holding Key], [Reference Date],Holding,[Currency Type],[Data Availability],[Current Value],[Current Cost],[Realized]
     from #TestInvestments_USD_Only
    union all
    select Investment, [Holding Key], ref_date, NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,  NULL,  NULL
    from (select dateadd(q,1,max([reference date])) as ref_date from #TestInvestments_USD_Only) as a
    cross join (select distinct Investment from #TestInvestments_USD_Only) as b
    cross join (select distinct [Holding Key] from #TestInvestments_USD_Only) as c
    --cross join (select distinct [Currency Type] from #TestInvestments_USD_Only) as d
    order by Investment, [Holding Key], [Reference Date], [Current Value] desc;
open c;

--Set the most recent data = to the reference date we are currently looking at (if missing data, then set the latest data = current quarter in the loop)
fetch next from c into @Investment,@HoldingKey,@ReferenceDate,@Holding,@CurrencyType,@DataAvailability,@CurrentValue,@CurrentCost,@Realized;  
select
    @prev_Investment=@Investment,
    @prev_HoldingKey=@HoldingKey,
    @prev_ReferenceDate=@ReferenceDate,
    @prev_Holding=@Holding,
    @prev_CurrencyType=@CurrencyType,
    @prev_DataAvailability=@DataAvailability,
    @prev_CurrentValue=@CurrentValue,
    @prev_CurrentCost=@CurrentCost,
    @prev_Realized=@Realized
;


--Insert the missing data into the temp table
while @@fetch_status = 0 begin
  fetch next from c into @Investment,@HoldingKey,@ReferenceDate,@Holding,@CurrencyType,@DataAvailability,@CurrentValue,@CurrentCost,@Realized;
  set @qdiff = datediff(q, @prev_ReferenceDate, @ReferenceDate);
  if @prev_Investment = @Investment and
     @prev_HoldingKey = @HoldingKey and
     @qdiff > 1
  begin
    insert into #TestInvestments_LatestAvailable_USD([Investment],[Holding Key],[Reference Date],[Holding],[Currency Type],[Data Availability],[Current Value],[Current Cost],Realized)
  select
        @prev_Investment,@prev_HoldingKey,eomonth(dateadd(q, #nums.n, @prev_ReferenceDate)),@prev_Holding,@prev_CurrencyType,@prev_DataAvailability,@prev_CurrentValue,@prev_CurrentCost,@prev_Realized
      from #nums
      where #nums.n < @qdiff + iif(@CurrentValue = -1, 1, 0);
  end;
  select
    @prev_Investment=@Investment,
    @prev_ReferenceDate=@ReferenceDate,
    @prev_HoldingKey=@HoldingKey,
    @prev_Holding=@Holding,
    @prev_CurrencyType=@CurrencyType,
    @prev_DataAvailability=@DataAvailability,
    @prev_CurrentValue=@CurrentValue,
    @prev_CurrentCost=@CurrentCost,
    @prev_Realized=@Realized
        
END
CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c

--//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/*                       *******************     Local Currency Only in this section - below USD is the Local       *******************************   */

IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB.dbo.#TestInvestments_Local_Only') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TestInvestments_Local_Only
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB.dbo.#Local_nums') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Local_nums
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB.dbo.#TestInvestments_LatestAvailable_Local') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TestInvestments_LatestAvailable_Local

/*create temp table for USD Holdings only - Local Currency is unioned later*/
Select * into #TestInvestments_Local_Only from TestInvestments where [Currency Type] = 'Local' 


--create temp table to hold the local missing holdings
CREATE TABLE #TestInvestments_LatestAvailable_Local(
  [Reference Date] date  NOT NULL
  ,Investment nvarchar (200) NOT NULL
  ,[Holding Key] int NOT NULL
  ,Holding nvarchar (200) NOT NULL
  ,[Currency Type] [varchar](100) NULL
  ,[Data Availability] varchar(100) NULL
  ,[Current Value] [float] NULL
  ,[Current Cost] [float] NULL
  ,[Realized] [float] NULL
  ,primary key(Investment, [Holding Key], [Reference Date])
);

--cartesian join to create a table of row numbers (65,536 rows)
create table #Local_nums(n integer not null primary key);
with
  p1 as (select 0 as n union all select 0), -- 2
  p2 as (select 0 as n from p1 cross join p1 as b), -- 4
  p3 as (select 0 as n from p2 cross join p2 as b), -- 16
  p4 as (select 0 as n from p3 cross join p3 as b), -- 256
  p5 as (select 0 as n from p4 cross join p4 as b) -- 65536
insert into #Local_nums(n) select row_number() over(order by (select 0)) from p5;

--Create Variables for all of the USD columns to store the missing rows
declare

@local_prev_Investment nvarchar(200) ,@local_Investment nvarchar(200),
@local_prev_HoldingKey int, @local_HoldingKey int,
@local_prev_ReferenceDate date ,@local_ReferenceDate date,
@local_prev_Holding nvarchar(200) ,@local_Holding nvarchar(200),
@local_prev_CurrencyType varchar(100) ,@local_CurrencyType varchar(100),
@local_prev_DataAvailability varchar(100),@local_DataAvailability varchar(100),
@local_prev_CurrentValue float ,@local_CurrentValue float,
@local_prev_CurrentCost float ,@local_CurrentCost float,
@local_prev_Realized float ,@local_Realized float,
@local_qdiff integer;
    
--Begin loop for USD to look for missing rows and add them as variables
declare
  d cursor forward_only static read_only for
    select Investment, [Holding Key], [Reference Date],Holding,[Currency Type],[Data Availability],[Current Value],[Current Cost],[Realized]
     from #TestInvestments_Local_Only
    union all
    select Investment, [Holding Key], ref_date, NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,  NULL,  NULL
    from (select dateadd(q,1,max([reference date])) as ref_date from #TestInvestments_Local_Only) as a
    cross join (select distinct Investment from #TestInvestments_Local_Only) as b
    cross join (select distinct [Holding Key] from #TestInvestments_Local_Only) as d
    --cross join (select distinct [Currency Type] from #TestInvestments_Local_Only) as d
    order by Investment, [Holding Key], [Reference Date], [Current Value] desc;
open d;

--Set the most recent data = to the reference date we are currently looking at (if missing data, then set the latest data = current quarter in the loop)
fetch next from d into @local_Investment,@local_HoldingKey,@local_ReferenceDate,@local_Holding,@local_CurrencyType,@local_DataAvailability,@local_CurrentValue,@local_CurrentCost,@local_Realized;  
select
    @local_prev_Investment=@local_Investment,
    @local_prev_HoldingKey=@local_HoldingKey,
    @local_prev_ReferenceDate=@local_ReferenceDate,
    @local_prev_Holding=@local_Holding,
    @local_prev_CurrencyType=@local_CurrencyType,
    @local_prev_DataAvailability=@local_DataAvailability,
    @local_prev_CurrentValue=@local_CurrentValue,
    @local_prev_CurrentCost=@local_CurrentCost,
    @local_prev_Realized=@local_Realized;

--Insert the missing data into the temp table
while @@fetch_status = 0 begin
  fetch next from d into @local_Investment,@local_HoldingKey,@local_ReferenceDate,@local_Holding,@local_CurrencyType,@local_DataAvailability,@local_CurrentValue,@local_CurrentCost,@local_Realized;
  set @local_qdiff = datediff(q, @local_prev_ReferenceDate, @local_ReferenceDate);
  if @local_prev_Investment = @local_Investment and
     @local_prev_HoldingKey = @local_HoldingKey and
     @local_qdiff > 1
  begin
    insert into #TestInvestments_LatestAvailable_Local([Investment],[Holding Key],[Reference Date],[Holding],[Currency Type],[Data Availability],[Current Value],[Current Cost],Realized)
  select
        @local_prev_Investment,@local_prev_HoldingKey,eomonth(dateadd(q, #Local_nums.n, @local_prev_ReferenceDate)),@local_prev_Holding,@local_CurrencyType,@local_DataAvailability,@local_CurrentValue,@local_CurrentCost,@local_Realized  
      from #Local_nums
      where #Local_nums.n < @local_qdiff + iif(@local_CurrentValue = -1, 1, 0);
  end;
  select
    @local_prev_Investment=@local_Investment,
    @local_prev_HoldingKey=@local_HoldingKey,   
    @local_prev_ReferenceDate=@local_ReferenceDate,
    @local_prev_Holding=@local_Holding,
    @local_prev_CurrencyType=@local_CurrencyType,
    @local_prev_DataAvailability=@local_DataAvailability,
    @local_prev_CurrentValue=@local_CurrentValue,
    @local_prev_CurrentCost=@local_CurrentCost,
    @local_prev_Realized=@local_Realized;
end
close d
deallocate d

/*Had to add an extra quarter to get the maximum reference date for the current quarter, otherwise the max date was the max date that the fund reported
Below, I delete anything that went past the current MAX reference date for ALL FUNDS (not just a specific fund)*/

DELETE FROM #TestInvestments_LatestAvailable_Local WHERE [Reference Date] >= (select DATEADD(q,1,MAX([Reference Date])) from TestInvestments)
DELETE FROM #TestInvestments_LatestAvailable_USD WHERE [Reference Date] >= (select DATEADD(q,1,MAX([Reference Date])) from TestInvestments)

/*statement to insert missing holdings into current TestInvestments table*/

Insert into TestInvestments ([Data Availability],[Investment],[Holding Key],[Holding],[Reference Date],[Currency Type],[Current Value],[Current Cost],Realized)
        select  [Data Availability] = 'Include Latest from Previous Submissions',[Investment],[Holding Key],[Holding],[Reference Date],[Currency Type],[Current Value],[Current Cost],Realized
        from #TestInvestments_LatestAvailable_Local
        union
        select [Data Availability] = 'Include Latest from Previous Submissions',[Investment],[Holding Key],[Holding],[Reference Date],[Currency Type],[Current Value],[Current Cost],Realized
        from #TestInvestments_LatestAvailable_USD
```

Thank you so much for any help you can provide!

Comment: Sounds like you need to start with a calendar table to fill in your "gaps" Though you don't actually explain the logic here, which doesn't really help us help you.

Comment: Hi @Larnu, I'm sorry, I thought I explained it above.  Is there something that I need to elaborate on?  I didn't want my post to be so long that no one read it, but want it to be clear.  EDIT: I used a calendar table, but that just showed me a single blank row for an entire quarter that was missing, which is normally many rows for each individual holding.

Comment: Perhaps focus on a few specific examples to demonstrate what's missing and why. At the moment you've given us 48 rows or data, and then ~100 and it feels like you want us to work out the difference.

Comment: Okay, sounds good.  I'll edit the post.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you @Larnu, I've reduced the table size and added in bold the exact issue with the data.

Comment: So do you need a new row per currency, but not holding? YOu haven't explained the logic here, so it's still guess work. We still need to guess.

Comment: Hi Larnu, We need a new row based on the investments most recent holding for both Local and USD Currency Types for the missing quarter-ends.  I've added to the post.  Thank you.

Comment: I've added to the post with my previous fix and why it won't work.  Thank you for the help.  @Larnu, I've completely redone the post.  Hopefully this is more clear now.

Comment: The question need to be stand-alone, fiddles are helpful to assist, but the query needs to be in the question.

Comment: You can create the tables in dbfiddle.uk and provide the link. This will not only make your post more readable but also you can verify that the create and insert statements are working. For example, the second create table statement doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Hi @OkechukwuOssai, I have fixed that second query.  I will provide my current solution that is not working as intended here for Dale K and on dbfiddle.uk.  Thank you.

Comment: @DaleK, I included current solution above.  I'm trying to not be in a cursor and prevent bringing forward holdings like TransUnion mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up being able to fill in gaps in data and bring forward data to present day using a set based solution to replace the cursor I had previously, that was too granular (based on missing holding, instead of missing investment and populating latest holdings based on that investment):

```
/*                    -----------First part of code only fills the gaps in the data - does not bring forward data to current date---------                  */


/*Get max date to bring holdings forward*/
Drop table if exists #MaxDatefromUholdings
Select Max([Reference Date]) as MaxD 
into #MaxDatefromUholdings from TestInvestmentsFixed

Drop table if exists #Quarter
select distinct LastDayOfQuarter into #Quarter
from trsinvsqlp.ctrl.dbo.datedim
where LastDayOfQuarter between '3/1/2018' and (Select MaxD from #MaxDatefromUholdings) --First date we received holdings to max date of the portfolio

Drop table if exists #MissingHolding
/*Get first date an investment was submitted so cross join doesn't populate dates from the datedim table before this*/
;with tbl_Holding as (
    select  holding,
            investment,
            [Currency Type],
            min([Reference Date]) ReferenceDateMin,
            max([Reference Date]) ReferenceDateMax
    from TestInvestmentsFixed
    group by holding, investment, [Currency Type]
)
/*Get all combinations of dates and holdings*/
select  tbl_Holding.holding,
        tbl_Holding.investment,
        tbl_Holding.[Currency Type],
        lastdayofquarter,
        tbl_Holding.ReferenceDateMax,
        ReferenceDateMin 
into #MissingHolding
from tbl_Holding
    cross join #Quarter
where 1 = 1
    and #Quarter.LastDayOfQuarter >= tbl_Holding.ReferenceDateMin /*Filter cross join - Grab latest available greater than 1st time an investment submitted*/
    and #Quarter.LastDayOfQuarter <= ReferenceDateMax /*LastDayofQuart less than last submission date by investment - omit data where a manager hasn't submitted yet - this is taken care of in second part of code*/
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from TestInvestmentsFixed tbl_ActualHolding
        where tbl_Holding.[Currency Type] = tbl_ActualHolding.[Currency Type]
         and tbl_Holding.investment = tbl_ActualHolding.investment
         --and tbl_Holding.Holdingskey = tbl_ActualHolding.Holdingskey
         and #Quarter.LastDayOfQuarter = tbl_ActualHolding.[Reference Date]
    ) --Finds data in the cross joined table, not currently in TestInvestmentsFixed

Drop table if exists #HoldingsGapsFilled
;with tbl_MissingHolding as (
    select  #MissingHolding.holding as L_holding,
            [L_Data Availability Missing] = 'Include Latest from Previous Submissions',
            #MissingHolding.investment as L_investment,
            #MissingHolding.[Currency Type] as [L_Currency Type],
            #MissingHolding.LastDayOfQuarter,
            #MissingHolding.ReferenceDateMin,
            max(TestInvestmentsFixed.[Reference Date]) ReferenceDateLast
    from #MissingHolding
        join TestInvestmentsFixed
         on #MissingHolding.holding=TestInvestmentsFixed.Holding
          and #MissingHolding.investment = TestInvestmentsFixed.Investment
          and #MissingHolding.[Currency Type] = TestInvestmentsFixed.[currency type]
          and #MissingHolding.LastDayOfQuarter > TestInvestmentsFixed.[Reference Date] /*Pulls in latest within data gaps available only*/
    group by #MissingHolding.holding,
            #MissingHolding.investment,
            #MissingHolding.[Currency Type],
            #MissingHolding.LastDayOfQuarter,
            #MissingHolding.ReferenceDateMin
)
/*Add rest of columns from TestInvestmentsFixed to latest available data*/
select tbl_MissingHolding.*,TestInvestmentsFixed.*
into #HoldingsGapsFilled
from tbl_MissingHolding
    join TestInvestmentsFixed
     on tbl_MissingHolding.L_holding=TestInvestmentsFixed.Holding
          and tbl_MissingHolding.L_investment = TestInvestmentsFixed.Investment
          and tbl_MissingHolding.[L_Currency Type] = TestInvestmentsFixed.[currency type]
          and tbl_MissingHolding.ReferenceDateLast = TestInvestmentsFixed.[Reference Date]

/*         ----------Second part of code brings forward investments from their max submission date from the last date that an investment submitted---------                  */

Drop table if exists #HoldingsSinceLatestSubmission

--Get last submission date for each investment
;With AddFutureStuff as (
    select distinct 
            investment as Distinct_Investment,
            max([Reference Date]) LastSubmissionDate
    from TestInvestmentsFixed
    group by investment
    ),
    --Get max date for entire portfolio
    MaxDateofPortfolio as (
    Select max([Reference Date]) as MaxPortfolioDate
    from TestInvestmentsFixed
    ),
    --Combine last date an investment submitted with the max date for the entire portfolio
    DatesBetween as ( 
    select Distinct_Investment, LastSubmissionDate, (select MaxPortfolioDate from MaxDateofPortfolio) as MaxPortfolioDate
    from AddFutureStuff
    )
    select #Quarter.LastDayOfQuarter, 
            DatesBetween.*,
            TestInvestmentsFixed.* 
    into #HoldingsSinceLatestSubmission
    from DatesBetween
    --Join TestInvestmentsFixed to pull in all other columns from TestInvestmentsFixed with last submission dates and max portfolio date
    join TestInvestmentsFixed 
    on TestInvestmentsFixed.[Reference Date] = DatesBetween.LastSubmissionDate
    and TestInvestmentsFixed.investment = DatesBetween.Distinct_Investment
    --Cross join to populate table for all dates between last submission date (by investment) and max portfolio date
    cross join #Quarter
    where #quarter.LastDayOfQuarter > LastSubmissionDate and #quarter.LastDayOfQuarter <= MaxPortfolioDate --Ensures cross join is only between latest submission and max Portfolio date
    and LastSubmissionDate <> MaxPortfolioDate --Remove any holdings submitted in the current quarter
    order by TestInvestmentsFixed.Investment, #Quarter.LastDayOfQuarter
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to ascertain as your scenario is it a bit ambiguous. From your comments it seems like you are simply trying to do two things:

1. Have a row for each group for each quarter even if no data exists
2. For where there is no data, pull in the most recent historical value (CROSS APPLY is perfect for this)

### Solution

```
;WITH cte_GenerateQuarters AS (
    SELECT [Reference Date] = CAST('2019-12-31' AS DATE) /*Start date*/
    UNION ALL
    SELECT EOMONTH(DATEADD(qq,1,[Reference Date]))
    FROM cte_GenerateQuarters
    WHERE [Reference Date] < '2022-06-30' /*End date*/
),
cte_DistinctGroups AS (
    /*1 row for each "group"*/
    SELECT Investment,Holding,[Currency Type]
    FROM TestInvestments
    GROUP BY Investment,Holding,[Currency Type]
),
cte_DistinctRows AS (
    /*Generates 1 row per each date,investment,holding,currency type*/
    SELECT A.*,b.[Reference Date]
    FROM cte_DistinctGroups AS A
    CROSS JOIN cte_GenerateQuarters AS B
    )
SELECT
A.Investment
,A.Holding
,A.[Currency Type]
,A.[Reference Date]
,Realized = ISNULL(B.Realized,C.Realized)
,CASE WHEN B.Realized IS NOT NULL THEN 'Realized = Reported Value' ELSE 'Realized = Pulled from history' END
FROM cte_DistinctRows AS A
LEFT JOIN TestInvestments AS B /*Reported data for specific quarter*/
    on A.Investment = B.Investment
    AND A.Holding = B.Holding
    AND A.[Currency Type] = B.[Currency Type]
    AND A.[Reference Date] = B.[Reference Date]
OUTER APPLY (
    /*Pulls in historical quarter data*/
    SELECT TOP(1) *
    FROM TestInvestments AS DTA
    WHERE DTA.Investment = A.Investment
    AND DTA.Holding = A.Holding
    AND DTA.[Currency Type] = A.[Currency Type]
    AND A.[Reference Date] >= DTA.[Reference Date]
    ORDER BY DTA.[Reference Date] DESC
) AS C
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) /*Used to in case you need to generate more than 25 quarters via recursion*/
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Stephan.  I wound up solving this, but your solution looks like it would have worked.